Lifting state through multiple child elements
Bit stuck on this. I have a Main parent component that goes to a Search component which then goes to a Select component. The search asks for a city and then goes to an API and brings back 5 search results and I send them to the select component where I map the results into a selection form. Once the user selects the city and submits it I need the selection to be stored somewhere in the main so I can use it on other children. Any help is appreciated, still getting a handle on React.
I've tried just making the Select component a direct child of the main but it didn't like that.
I've tried sending the "cityObj" down through the search into the select but no luck, unless I just did something wrong.
I thought maybe making the "Body" component that needs the info a child of the "Select" but I'm still working on that.
Main.js
function Main() {
    const [cityObj, setCityObj] = React.useState('');
    return (
        <div className="container p-5 bg-primary">
            <i className='text-danger fw-bold'>Main component</i>
            <h2 className='m-3'>My React Weather Application</h2>
            <Search />
            <hr />
            <Body />
        </div>
    );
}

Search.js
function Search(props) {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');
    const [cityArray, setCityArray] = React.useState([]);
    const [cel, setCel] = React.useState(null);
    const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = React.useState(null);
    

    const Weather_API_key = '55c5392db030dbb75249aa1ff9b8a871';
    const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct';
    

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log('The form submitted with input: ' + searchTerm);
        setCel(() => (searchTerm - 32) / 1.8);
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior 
        console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(`${url}?q=${searchTerm}&limit=5&appid=${Weather_API_key}&units=metric`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setCityArray(data);
                console.log('API data came mounted');
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className="container p-3 bg-success">
            <i className='text-danger fw-bold'>Search component</i>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='my-3 row g-3'>
                <label className="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                    Please enter city name:
                </label>
                <div className="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" value={searchTerm}
                        onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" className="btn btn-primary mb-3" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <Select cityArray={cityArray} />
        </div>
    );
}


Select.js
function Select(props) {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = React.useState('');
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(null);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        // Get the input from the user and save it in a state variable
        // event.target is the input element
        setUserInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log('The form submitted with input: ' + userInput);
        setSelectedValue(() => userInput);
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior 
    }
    return (
        <div className="container p-3 bg-warning">
            <i className='text-danger fw-bold'>Select component</i>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className=' row g-3'>
                <label className="col-sm col-form-label">
                    Choose your country:</label>
                <select value={userInput} onChange={handleChange}
                    className='form-select col-md'>
                   {props.cityArray.map((city, index) =>
                        <option key={city.name + index} value={`${city.name} , ${city.country}`}>
                            {city.name}, {city.country}</option>
                    )}
                </select>
                <div className="col-sm col-form-label">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-3" />
                </div>
            </form>

            {
                selectedValue &&
                <div> You selected {selectedValue} </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}



A solution would be to use React Context. What is React Context? It is a state in React and it functions like a useState hook. The big difference is, while creating a context, it can be wrapped around a component or components and all those components will have access to the state, without the need to pass the props up or down. I will write a short example, how it would look like:
Main.js:
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const CityContext = createContext();

export function Main() {
  const [cityObj, setCityObj] = useState();

  return (
    <CityContext.Provider value={{ cityObj, setCityObj }}>
      <Search />
      <Body />
    </CityContext.Provider>
  );
}

In the code above, we created a context with the createContext hook and wrapped it around our Search and Body component. Now ALL the components inside the Context Provider have access to cityObj and setCityObj. How can we use and change the context?
Search.js
  let { cityObj, setCityObj } = useContext(CityContext);

  const changeCityState = () => {
    setCityObj({exampleObj: "example"});
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {cityObj}
    </div>
  );

In the code Above we use the useContext hook and pass the CityContext as a parameter to access the value of the context provider. Now we can use the context the same as a "normal" state. If you change the state, EVERY component will be rerenderd, where the state is being used! I recommend to read more on (https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext).

Would this work to access my select component as well? Right now the structure is Main - Search - Select. Select is a child of Search. Are you declaring the CityContext outside of the main function?

Im getting alot of errorswhen trying to use this.

I get errors like this as soon as i put the new code into my Main section

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useState')

The code was not meant to work as a copy and paste solution, it is just to illustrate how it would look like in your code. The link doc I posted has a working example, which you can use.

Yes, the provider which you wrapp your components around, can be used inside all components its wrapped around and its child components aswell

If you want you can create a reproducable example with your code, inside Sandbox or something else and I can show how to use the context and explain it.

That would be great, I’ll try and get something together ASAP

This link should work, its all under the folder "section A" and i included the root HTML file https://codesandbox.io/p/live/8d22195b-d51b-447a-aafa-2eb53d89a662

Yes give me some time

I appreciate it, thank you very much

I updated the code sandbox. I am not sure on how to test it, because its all in a seperate folder, which is not being used. But I am sure this the way it should work. If its not working I will otherwise add a minimal example inside the "src" folder to show you. I hope this helps!

Hey i think its starting to work but as soon as I put the import line at the top it gives me an error

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Are you importing it via require? I think this wont work, you have to use import {...} from "react";

And when i add it to the search component i get the same error plus

Uncaught ReferenceError: createContext is not defined

im not sure what require is but ive just copied the import tag that you have in the sandbox code and its doesnt seem to like it

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
